# Read array from Firebase Document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of URLS stored within a document that i'd like to read and display as individual cards. All I'm getting is the return of the whole array, I'm not mapping it correctly and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Currently, it's displaying "https://website1.com, https://website2.com". Where as I would like it to be individual items.

```
const getInternalLinks = async () => {
      try {
        const query = await db
          .collection("internallinks")
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setInternalLinks(tempData);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    };
  };

useEffect(() => {
    getInternalLinks()
},[])

return (
  {internalLinks.map((doc, index) => {
    <Card>
      <p>{doc.urls.urls}</p>
    </Card>
  }))
);
```

Firebase Collection Structure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it directly to the state:

```
const [internalLinks, setInternalLinks] = useState([]);

const getInternalLinks = async () => {
      try {
        const query = await db
          .collection("internallinks")
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data();
              setInternalLinks([ ...internalLinks, data ]);
            });
            
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    };
  };
```